# Selenium + Java = Assertion error

Tags: java, selenium, junit, assertion

I already have this kind of error, and I still don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

I need to assert true if I get a text in the page source.

So here is my method:

```
public boolean AssertSearch() {                 
    return driver.getPageSource().contains("Item found");               
}
```

And here is my assert:

```
assertTrue(buscarnok.validabuscaNOK());
```

And I keep receiving the message "Assertion Error". I don't know why. If I change the `"return driver.getPageSource().contains("Item found");"`to `driver.findelement(by.id("someID")).isdisplayed();`it works fine, so why isn't it working with getpagesource?

Comment: is the "Item Found" contained in the source or added later (after the search is done)?

Comment: After the search. Once the search is successfully done, the page displays the message "item found" with the item 's details

Comment: Then the text is not found in the page source, is it?  What you want is to find text (on the HTML)

Answer (score 1):

If the text you are looking for is not initially in the page or if it is hidden, it may not find it.

Try something like this:

```
String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
Assert.assertTrue("Item Found", bodyText.contains(text));
```

You can narrow down the search by selecting a different tag name or even a `div` by its `class` or `id`